# Shape of sp³ hybrid orbital

Tags: hybridization

I have a doubt regarding the shape of the $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridised orbital. I looked up for it on stackexchange and found a post where the guy said that where ever the orbitals interfere with opposite signs of the wavefunction they cancel out and hence we get a small lobe . 
He further said that when the right side of the p orbital overlaps with s orbital( i have linked the post) they both add up.

But the $\mathrm{s}$ orbital wavefunction can also have negative sign (in the post the guy has assumed that s orbital wavefunction is always positive) . So in all four interference combinations are possible : ++ , +- , -+ , - - . Hence the shape should be different  but its not.

I am really confused about this. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.
Link to original post : https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/15909

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't put too much trust in the absolute signs of wavefunction, for they all are arbitrary anyway. Look at it this way: an ***s*** orbital has one sign (*). One lobe of ***p*** orbital has the same sign, so when they add up, it grows huge. Another lobe inevitably has the *opposite* sign, so when they interfere, it is reduced to a tiny pig tail.

---

(*) This is not quite true if we consider radial nodes. That's when things get really hairy.

Comment: I think this answer says what I meant to say. I'll delete mine, you were 33 seconds earlier, after all =D

Comment: Great minds think alike, they say.

Comment: but what will happen if s has two signs ( positive and negative ) . Thanks

Comment: That can't happen. Every ***s*** orbital looks _from the outside_ exactly the same: as a nice furry ball of one color (one sign, that is).

Comment: @user8167818 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Qualitative_understanding_of_shapes is a good way of trying to understand orbitals, IMO.