# What is the type of orbital depicted in this diagram?

Tags: orbitals

The following image is from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/15909/81509) for the question [Why is one lobe of an sp3 hybridized orbital smaller than its other half?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15907/81509):

[image]

I understood everything from that answer, but couldn't identify what is the type of orbital marked by the red circle. It could not be a $d_{z^2}$ orbital with $x$ axis as it's $z$ axis, as it has a big spherical node and not a circular ring? I haven't encountered such an orbital till now.

Comment: That's probably a very poorly drawn cartoon of a $d_{x^2-y^2}$ see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital . The "empty" lobes are along y and cancel the density in the annulus on the xy plane of the $d_{z^2}$ orbital at left.

Comment: @BuckThorn, Thank you. Could you please explain your second sentence - How can two lobes having the same sign of wave function cancel each other destructively to give $d_{z^2-x^2}$ orbital?

Comment: There is a negative sign on front of the orbital, if you look closely, which inverts the sign (I guess that means phase, actually) of the wavefunction.